# emulator command doesn't work in crontab (start GUI in contab)

Tags: android, user-interface, automation, emulation, cron

I've wrote a script test.sh for android automation testing, here require start emulator each time

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/xxx/tool/jdk1.6.0_34/bin:/home/xxx/tool/android-sdk-linux/tools:"
emulator -avd avd22
```

I put test.sh in crontab, but looks emulator can't come up in crontab, but manually I execute test.sh, all things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

fix it by adding following command before emulator command

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && emulator -avd avd22
```